# Column value replace

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe whose col_3 is `df['col_1].map(str) +','+df['col_2].map(str)`

```
col_1         col_2       col_3
abccd                    ['abccd','nan']
mmdf          Hgfg       ['mmdf','Hgfg']
abccd         ddsx       ['abccd','ddsx']
hhdy                     ['hhdy','nan']
```

Clearly the 'nan' is being created as Col_2 is blank. 
My question is: How can I replace the 'nan' with Col_1 values i.e. whenever Col_2 value is empty Col_3 would be `df['col_1].map(str) +','+df['col_1].map(str)`
Please help

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: desired output would be ['abccd','abccd'] on row 1 of Col_3 and like this

Comment: you need to try , `df.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)`

Answer (score 1):

use `df.replace()`

```
 df['col_3'] = df['col_1'].map(str) +','+df['col_2'].replace(np.nan, df['col_1']).map(str)
```

based on your output it looks like your values in df['col_2'] are np.nan if they're not you may need to replace an empty string and not np.nan

Answer (score 1):

An appropriate solution will depend on whether you want a series of strings or a series of lists. You can use [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) for the first and [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) for the second case:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1': ['abccd', 'mmdf', 'abccd', 'hhdy'],
                   'col_2': [np.nan, 'Hgfg', 'ddsx', np.nan]})

df['col_3'] = df['col_1'].map(str) + ',' + df['col_2'].fillna(df['col_1']).map(str)
df['col_4'] = df[['col_1', 'col_2']].ffill(1).values.tolist()

print(df)

   col_1 col_2        col_3           col_4
0  abccd   NaN  abccd,abccd  [abccd, abccd]
1   mmdf  Hgfg    mmdf,Hgfg    [mmdf, Hgfg]
2  abccd  ddsx   abccd,ddsx   [abccd, ddsx]
3   hhdy   NaN    hhdy,hhdy    [hhdy, hhdy]
```

Usual disclaimers apply: you should try and avoid lists in `pd.Series` objects as you now have 2 layers of pointers in an `object` dtype series.